# Proving a sequence $(a_n)$ converges under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Suppose $(a_n)$ satisfies the condition
>
> $$ |a_{n+1} - a_{n+2} | \leq \alpha |a_n - a_{n+1} | $$
>
> for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Carefully, prove that $(a_n)$ converges.

### ATTEMPT:

First, notice that $$|a_{n+1} - a_{n+2} | \leq \alpha |a_n-a_{n+1}| \leq \alpha^2 |a_{n-1} - a_n |  \leq \alpha^3 |a_{n-2} - a_{n-1}| \leq ... \leq \alpha^{n-1} |a_2-a_1|$$

Let $A = |a_2- a_1| \in \mathbb{R}$.

First, suppose $m>n$, then

$$ |a_n - a_m| = |a_n - a_{n+1} + a_{n+1} - a_m| = |(a_n - a_{n+1}) + (a_{n+1} - a_{n+2}) + ... + (a_{m-1} - a_m)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{m-n} \alpha^{j+n-3} \cdot A$$

Now, We know that $\sum_{j=1}^{m-n} \alpha^{j+n-3} = \alpha^{n-3} \left( \dfrac{ 1- \alpha^{m-n+1 }}{1- \alpha } \right) = \dfrac{ \alpha^{n-3} - \alpha^{m-2} }{\alpha-1} < \dfrac{\alpha^{n-3} }{\alpha-1} = \dfrac{\alpha^n}{\alpha^3(\alpha-1)}$

Thus, $|a_n - a_m| < \alpha^n \cdot \dfrac{A}{\alpha^3 (\alpha-1)} $

So, let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $N > \dfrac{ \log(A/(\epsilon \alpha^2(\alpha-1) ) }{log(1/\alpha) } $ and for any $m>n>N$, we obtain

$$ |a_n - a_m | < \epsilon $$

So the sequence is Cauchy thus convergent.

Is this a correct solution?

Comment: I didn't check every detail but it's definitely the right idea!

Comment: In the lines after "Now, We know that", the terms $\alpha -1$ in the denominators should be $1-\alpha.$ (Typo?). It's good. You can shorten it a bit: $|a_n-a_m|<\alpha^n\cdot A/\alpha^3(1-\alpha)=F(n)$ for all $m>n$  implies $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>n}|a_n-a_m|\le \lim_{n\to \infty}F(n)=0$, so the Cauchy Convergence Condition is met.

Comment: Making the geometric series appear is actually just a manual application of ratio test for series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution works, but I just wanted to give an alternative solution, since you wanted a different look at the problem. Let $y_n := x_{n + 1} - x_n$. Note that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n$ is absolutely convergent, since

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n| \leq y_1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha^{n-1} < \infty,$$

using the fact that $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Now, by telescoping, we have that

$$x_n = x_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n - 1}y_k.$$

Therefore, taking limits of both sides, we obtain the desired result.